# how to snap several vertices to the same z.position

Tags: snapping

I encountered a little problem. Say I have a mesh an the Vertices on top are not in the same Z-Position. I am looking for a method to have them all aligned in Z.

My approach is to select the 3 Vertices, grab the blue arrow to constrain the movement in the Z-Axis and want to snap to the vertex highlighted with the red circle.
[image]

My Snappingsettings 
[image]

But for some reason they don´t have the same z-Position. They seem to keep their Offsets to each other?

I used this method in Maya. 
Do you know a way how to get that working?

thanks in Advance
Guido.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can select the vertices and then hit <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then they'll have the same Z-Position.

<kbd>S</kbd> is the shortcut key for "Scale". <kbd>Z</kbd> is the the axis to scale on and <kbd>0</kbd> is the amount to scale by.

[image: Scaling on the Z-axis]

Or, if you wanted to align the vertices to a specific vertex, you can:

- Select the vertex you want to align to
- Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select Cursor to Selected.
- Change the pivot point to 3D Cursor
- Select the other vertices and hit <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Or alternatively (without the need to change the pivot point to 3D Cursor), you can

- Select "Snap Element" on the 3D Header and select "Vertex"
- Then select all the vertices **except** the one you want to align to
- Hit <kbd>G</kbd> to grab
- Then hit <kbd>Z</kbd> to constraint the translation to the Z axis
- Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hover the cursor over the vertex you want to align to until there's a circle over the vertex (don't hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> if the "Snap during transform" option is on)
- Then click (or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

[image: Align by snapping to a vertex]

Comment: Add an  explanation of what s, z, and the 0 key do, please

Comment: S = scale, Z = constrain the scale to the Z axis only, 0 is the numerical amount to scale on the Z axis. Nice post Kidus.

Comment: Big thanks you saved me a big amount of blood sweat and tears!

Answer (score -2):

well grabbing them is not the proper approach. You should scale them along Z to align them.