# How do I have the vertices selected below extend to the edge at the far right side?

Tags: vertices

Is there an automatic procedure that would connect the selected vertices to the white dots without using the knife tool to Individually connect them?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution could be one of the methods explained here: **[How to automatically complete these edge loops?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95037/how-to-automatically-complete-these-edge-loops)**

Or, The Add-on TinyCAD comes in handy to fix topology, and does exactly what I wanted, without much effort. A video demonstration is found here: **www.youtube.com/watch?v=Usx7C03P8Fs**

Answer (score 0):

If your problem of creating several faces is as simple as shown in this picture, my suggestion would be to do this:

- select all the vertices you want to form several quadratic faces.
- hit *F* and create an n-gon
- hit *CTRL T* to triangulate the faces, this results in your n-gon being converted to triangular faces.
- hit *ALT J* to convert tris to quads. This tool is then trying to convert the triangles you've previously created into the quadratic faces you've probably wanted.

(If you end up with something messy from the convert tris to quads function, try to tweak the settings in the toolbar. )

Comment: The solution provided does only make use of the existing vertices; what I wish to achieve is for new vertices to be created on the opposite side, and for the existing ones to be connected to those closest to them, which, if found in parallel to them, would result in straight edges.

Thank you.