# How to display background images in perspective?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I am trying to find out how to approach a relief type project.
I have a background image and a flat plane mesh to sculpt on, but I actually don´t see any changes looking straight on top. When I tilt the perspective a bit the image disappears.

Is there a way to make the image appear at all perspectives?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95039/how-to-add-reference-photos-in-orthographic-view-from-angles-other-than-the-defa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Background images will only be displayed in**

> Camera Prespective view (<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)

Any of the **Preset** Orthographic views

> - Front/Back (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>)
> - Right /Left (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>)
> - Top/Bottom (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>)

Background images will not show in perspective view.

To switch between Perspective and Orthographic view use <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>

Background images are used for reference only and will not be part of the final render.

---

**Alternatives to background images** are to use an empty as image or using a plane with the image mapped to it.

To use an empty as image use Add> Empty >Image

[image]

Select the image in the properties->Empty->Display tab

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the image as background for the world. Set the Texture coordinates to Window.

[image]