# I cannot open background image

Tags: image

I tried to open a background image (jpg) and it is not showing. I made sure I checked the background box and I also tried it with with many images. I saw tutorials and I cannot find any differences in the procedure, except in my case the image doesn't appear. Do you know what I maybe do wrong?

Comment: are you in orthographic mode? You won't see your background image if you're not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display background images in perspective?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96866/how-to-display-background-images-in-perspective) or [I set an image background image but can't see it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140964/i-set-an-background-image-but-i-cant-actually-see-it-all/140972#140972)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=background+image+not+show